# Trigger a profile in Sitecore DMS 7.5

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-dms, sitecore7.5

I was using the following code in sitecore 6.5 to trigger a profile :

```cs
var profile = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentVisit.GetOrCreateProfile("<Profile Name>");
profile.BeginEdit();
profile.Score("<profile key>",<profile key value you want to set>);
profile.Score("<profile key>",<profile key value you want to set>);
profile.UpdatePattern(); //sets the appropriate pattern based on the current profile keys values you have just set.
profile.EndEdit();
```

now it is not working with the new dms API, do you have any idea what should i use instead ?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```cs
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles
```

for this purpose

Comment: Just some clarification of the above. As of Sitecore 7.5 `Visits` are now called `Interactions`. `Visitors` are now called `Contacts`. The API has changed accordingly.

Comment: Do you have any code to achieve what Ayman is asking? The API has changed significantly and the same methods are not available on the Profiles class.

Answer (score 1):

Full code to trigger a profile in Sitecore 7.5+ is as follows:

```cs
        var profile = Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles["yourProfile"];
        var scores = new Dictionary<string, float>();
        scores.Add("key1", 5);
        scores.Add("key2", 10);
        profile.Score(scores);
```